# Front-end framework like Django's template framework/Jinja

Tags: javascript, django, frameworks, django-templates, frontend

I was wondering if there was a front-end (javascript?) framework that is similar to Django's template framework. 


I'm trying to render JSON using a Django-like template framework(or Jinja like). I need to be able to use `if statements` and `loops` that will or will not execute depending on the `if statement`. The framework doesn't need to have the template inheritance. 


I looked at [Angular.js](https://angularjs.org/) but although it has some similarities, it works really different. the only `if statement` I found was meant to delete/show `HTML` code, but you couldn't use a `if statement` to execute (or not execute) AngularJS code.


**TL;DR**

Is there a front-end framework that works like [JinJa](http://jinja.pocoo.org/)/Django's template framework?

Comment: You might have a look at Nunjucks. It's a port of Jinja to JavaScript, which you can use via Node or in the browser: https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/

Comment: This is perfect, can you make an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/) is a port of Jinja in JavaScript. You can use it browser or server-side. It has nearly all of the template tags you'd expect in Django and it's very easy to write your own tags and or filters.

Comment: It looks really promising but I can't get it to work. according to the official getting started I should link the .js file, and then...? I just can't get it to work. I searched for about 2 hours straight and can't find a good getting started guide if you want to use it browser-side. Can you help me or link me to a resource?

Comment: I haven't actually used Nunjucks in the browser, but I can throw together a quick test.

Comment: Here's a working example of rendering a json template: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2kbrhzst28u2w6o/nunjucks-test.zip?dl=0

Comment: I used gulp-serve since Nunjucks wants to use an Ajax request to get the template browser-side. Just run: `npm install` and then `gulp`, which will start up the serve task. Then you can view the result at localhost:3000

Comment: The docs you're looking for are at: https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/getting-started.html, specifically the "Usage" section

Comment: I looked at the usage section, but I havent used NODE, and im completely new to JS frameworks.(except JQuery). And about the your example, i'm on the phone atm so I can't try it. But since it uses localhost im guessing it needs a server? And this needs to run without a server. Is that possible?

Comment: Without seeing the actual use case of what you're trying to do, I can only speculate. Nunjucks will attempt to load whatever template you try to render client-side via an ajax request. So, you'll simply need to be able to serve that file. None of the code in the sample I put together requires any knowledge of Node.js, but it does require Node to run.

Comment: You can replace Node with your server of choice, and the code in the sample will still work.

Comment: I want to make an crosswalk app. This should be HTML(5)+JS and it should be able to run on the device with and without connection. It will be getting json data from a server running python. When it has no connection, it will use the data stored on the device using HTML5 local storage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103136/discussion-between-brandon-and-david-western).